# Collatz Conjecture: If a non-trivial cycle exists, would the sum of powers of $2$ be less than $2n$?

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, solution-verification, collatz-conjecture

For the [Collatz Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture), it seems to me that if $m$ is the sum of the powers of $2$ for a non-trivial $n$ cycle (where each $x_1, \dots, x_n $ is odd and $x_i > 1$), it follows that $m < 2n$

Is my reasoning correct?

**Let:**

- $\nu_2(x)$ be the [2-adic valuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order) of $x$
- $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$ be $n$ distinct integers such that:

  - $x_{i+1} = \dfrac{3x_i + 1}{2^{\nu_2(3x_i+1)}}$
  - $x_i > 1$

**Observations:**

- $\left(3 + \dfrac{1}{x_{i}}\right) = \left(\dfrac{x_{i+1}}{x_{i}}\right)2^{\nu_2(3x_{i} + 1)}$ since:

  - $x_{i+1} = \dfrac{3x_{i}+1}{2^{\nu_2(3x_{i}+1)}}$
  - $2^{\nu_2(3x_{i}+1)}x_{i+1} = 3x_{i} + 1$
- $\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}\left(3 + \frac{1}{x_i}\right) = \left(\dfrac{x_{n+1}}{x_1}\right)\prod\limits_{i=1}^n2^{\nu_2(3x_i + 1)}$

> This follows directly from the previous observation.

- $\left(3 + \dfrac{1}{x_{\text{max}}}\right)^{n} \le \left(\dfrac{x_{n+1}}{x_1}\right)\prod\limits_{i=1}^n2^{{\nu}_2(3x_i + 1)} \le \left(3 + \dfrac{1}{x_{\text{min}}}\right)^{n}$

> This follows directly from the previous observation.

**Claim:**

If $n \ge 1$, $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$ forms a cycle, then $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \nu_2(3x_i+1) < 2n$

**Argument:**

(1)  Assume $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$ form a cycle such that $x_{i+n} = x_i$

(2)  Let $m = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \nu_2(3x_i+1)$ so that:

$$\left(3 + \dfrac{1}{x_{\text{max}}}\right)^{n} \le 2^{m} \le \left(3 + \dfrac{1}{x_{\text{min}}}\right)^{n}$$

(3) Clearly, $2^m > 3^n$ so that: $2^{\frac{m}{n}} > 3$

(4) It follows:

- $$3 + \frac{1}{x_{\text{max}}} \le 2^{\frac{m}{n}} \le 3 + \frac{1}{x_{\text{min}}}$$
- $$\frac{1}{x_{\text{max}}} \le 2^{\frac{m}{n}} - 3 \le \frac{1}{x_{\text{min}}}$$
- $$x_{\text{max}} \ge \frac{1}{2^{\frac{m}{n}} - 3} \ge x_{\text{min}}$$

(5)  $2^{\frac{m}{n}} - 3 < 1$ since $x_{\text{min}} > 1$ and $2^{\frac{m}{n}} > 3$

(6) It follows:

- $$2^{\frac{m}{n}} < 2^2$$
- $$m < 2n$$

Comment: This seems to be correct. I've always put it this way $$ 3^n = (3+\frac1\infty)^n \lt 2^m \le (3+\frac11)^n=4^n=2^{2n} $$ because obviously $1 \le x_k \lt \infty$ and from there arrived at the same result as you.

Comment: Much clearer than my argument.  Thanks!  Still catching up on the basics.  :-)

Comment: Yes, and if you insert negative $x_k$ you arrive at the conditions for the cycles in the negative numbers (there we find 3 cyclic solutions)

Comment: Wow.  I did not consider negative numbers.  Great tip.  :-)

Comment: @LarryFreeman Your argument also seems correct to me. FYI, a minor point is the $p$-adic valuation function, instead of $v$, uses $\nu$ (i.e., `\nu`, which is a Greek letter). I realize that visually they're very similar, but I've seen this issue commented a couple of times on this site, so at least some people do notice it. You can also confirm this yourself by copying & pasting the formula (which is expressed in some form of LaTeX) from the Wikipedia article into some type of text document.

Comment: Thanks for the comment on p-adic valuation!  I'll use nu going forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MikeB almost pinned it.

In a cycle, it is believed (but not proved) that $m$ is the first exponent of $2$ that make $2^m$ larger than $3^n$, in other word, $m=\lceil n\cdot log_2(3)\rceil$:
$$n\cdot log_2(3)<m<n\cdot log_2(3)+1$$

Comment: Thanks for explaining!  I wasn't clear on MikeB's answer until you gave yours.  This really helped!

Comment: MikeB equation gives the lower bound ($n\cdot log_2(3)<m$), not the upper bound. That's why said "almost"

Comment: Isn't the lower bound straight forward from $2^m > 3^n$.  It follows that $m > \dfrac{n \ln 3}{\ln 2}$

Comment: Yes. and if he had started with the right notation $\frac{3^n}{2^{m}} < 1$ that's what he would have obtained

Answer (score 1):

[**Correction:** this argument contains a mistake]

Actually, a stronger result can be shown using the following argument:

Looking at both even and odd numbers in the cycle, it contains $n$ odd numbers and $m$ even numbers.

Since

$$ \frac{3^{m}}{2^{m+n}} <  1$$

it follows that

$$ 3^{m} < 2^{m+n} $$
$$ (\frac{3}{2})^m < 2^n $$
$$ m \cdot \ln (3/2) < n \cdot \ln 2 $$
$$ m < \frac{\ln 2}{\ln(3/2)}\cdot n < 1.71n $$

Comment: I am not clear why $\dfrac{3^m}{2^{m+n}} < 1$. Could you add more details to explain why this is true.

Comment: Could you please show how you arrive at your first formula? Usually, at the exponent of $3$ we have $n$ and at the exponent of$2$ we have $m$. (At least in the notation of this question. Is it just a typo?)

Comment: For a Collatz sequence $x_1,x_2,...,x_{t+1}$ with $x_{i+1}=x_i/2$ if $x_i$ is even and $x_{i+1}=(3x_i+1)/2$ if $x_i$ is odd - in other words $t$ steps in the Collatz graph.

Denote by $n$ the number of odd $x_i$s in the sequence and by $m$ the number of even $x_i$s in the sequence. Then $t=m+n$.

It can be shown by induction that

$$ x_{t+1} = \frac{3^n}{2^t}x_1 + A = \frac{3^n}{2^{m+n}}x_1 + A $$

for some $A>0$. Therefore if $x_{t+1}=x_1$ it follows that

$$ \frac{3^n}{2^{m+n}} < 1 $$

Comment: MikeB,  thanks for explaining!  I may be misunderstanding but doesn't this lead to $t = m+n < n + 1.71n = 2.71n$?  I like your insight! Isn't this result weaker than $2n$?  Sorry for not fully getting it.  Am I wrong?

Comment: Thanks @LarryFreeman. $m+n < 2.71n$ implies $m < 1.7n$, right?
I think we use the same definitions for $n$ and $m$.

Your $m = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\nu_2(3x_i+1)$ is exactly the number of even $x_i$s in the complete Collatz sequence (which includes also the even numbers).

Comment: MikeB, you get $\frac{3^n}{2^{m+n}} < 1$ in your comment but start with $\frac{3^m}{2^{m+n}} < 1$ in your post . Also Larry's $m$ is equivalent to your $m+n$

Comment: Hi @MikeB.   Collag3n makes a great point.  Your approach applies to the lower bound, not the upper bound.  While I like your approach a lot, I think that Collag3n has provided a clearer answer to my question.

Comment: @LarryFreeman you're right about the definition of $m$, I didn't count the extra 1 for each odd number. The argument I was trying to make indeed produces a lower bound: $3^n < 2^m$ implies $m > 1.58n$. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @Collag3n Thanks for finding the mistake!

Comment: MikeB - why not actually *correct* the mistake in your msg and make it a more worthful contribution? (Otherwise, if the correction makes the answer meaningless at all, one can also retract/delete that answer, so later readers are not irritated)