# Collatz Conjecture: For a cycle where the maximum odd integer is $x_{max}$, does it follow that $x_{max} < 3^n$

Tags: inequality, solution-verification, collatz-conjecture, exponential-diophantine-equations

I am working on understanding the upper limit in the case where a non-trivial cycle exists for the [Collatz Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture).

Is the following reasoning valid for establishing that the maximum odd integer in a cycle consisting $n$ odd integers is less than $3^n$?

Let:

- $\nu_2(x)$ be the [2-adic valuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order) of $x$
- $n > 5$ be an integer
- $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$ be the distinct odd integers that make up a cycle of length $n$ with:

  - $x_{i+1} = \dfrac{3x_i+1}{2^{\nu_2(3x_i+1)}}$
  - $x_{i+n} = x_i$
  - $x_{max}$ is the highest odd integer in the cycle
- $p_0, p_1, \dots p_n$ be integers such that:

  - $p_0 = 0$
  - $p_{i+1} = p_i + \nu_2(3x_{i+1}+1)$
  - $p_n > p_{n-1} > \dots > p_1 > p_0 = 0$

(1)  Since $x_1, \dots x_n$ is a cycle, we can assume that $x_1 = x_{max}$

(2)  It follows from reasoning in step 2 [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4079742/48606):
$$2^{p_n}x_{n+1} - 3^{n}x_1 = x_{max}\left(2^{p_n} - 3^n\right) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}3^{n-1-i}2^{p_i}$$

(3)  From reasoning [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3860175/48606) for a cycle:
$$p_n < 2n$$

(4)  $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}3^{n-1-i}2^{p_i} < 6^n$ since:

$$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}3^{n-1-i}2^{p_i} < 3^{n-1} + 4^{n-1} + (2^{2n-n+1})(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-2}3^{n-i-i}2^{i}) < 3^{n-1} + 4^{n-1} + 2^{n+1}(3^{n-1}-2^{n-1}) = 3^{n-1} + 4^{n-1} + 4(6^{n-1} - 4^{n-1}) < 6^{n-1} + 6^{n-1} + 4\times6^{n-1} = 6^n$$

(5) $2^{p_n} \ge 2^{\lceil{n}\log_2{3}\rceil} > 3^n$

- From reasoning [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4044330/48606), since $n > 5$, it follows that $2^{p_n} - 3^n > 2^n$
- It follows that $x_{max} < \dfrac{6^n}{2^n} = 3^n$

Did I make a mistake?  Is there any step that is unclear?  Is there a simpler argument to reach the same conclusion?

---

**Edit**:

There is no advantage to the 2 cases in step 5.  I have updated to simplify based on suggestions in the comment.

Comment: Hello, where does the $n+1$ comes from in $(2^{2n-n+1})(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-2}3^{n-i-i}2^{i})$? I get that $p_i$ can be replaced by $2n+i$ since $p_i<2n+i$, but from there....

Comment: @user489810 If $p_n < 2n$ and each $\nu_2(3x_i+1) \ge 1$, it follows that for a cycle of length $n$, the largest value of $p_1$ is less than $2n-n+1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The start of your reasoning is quite good, although there are some issues with your later steps. Otherwise, your arguments are basically correct.

In your (4), there are several relatively minor mistakes, but your overall upper bound still applies. Using your result of $p_n \lt 2n$, then each $p_{i+1} \gt p_{i}$ for $1 \le i \le n - 1$ means each lower index $p$ value must be at least one less than the one above, with this giving that for all $0 \le j \le n - 1$

$$p_{n-j} \lt 2n - j \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Thus, for example, $p_{n - 1} \lt 2n - 1$ and $p_i \lt 2n - (n - i) = n + i$ for all $1 \le i \le n$ (thus, for example, $p_1 \lt n + 1$). This then, along with $n \gt 5$, gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}3^{n-1-i}2^{p_i} & \lt 3^{n-1} + 2^{2n-1} + (2^n)\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-2}3^{n-1-i}2^{i}\right) \\
& = 3^{n-1} + 2(2^{2(n-1)}) + (2^n)((2)(3)(3^{n-2} - 2^{n-2})) \\
& = 3^{n-1} + 2(4^{n-1}) + (2^2)((2)(3))(6^{n-2} - 4^{n-2}) \\
& \lt 6^{n-1} + 6^{n-1} + (4)(6)(6^{n-2}) \\
& = 6^{n-1} + 6^{n-1} + 4(6^{n-1}) \\
& = 6^n
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

You made a mistake with using $4^{n-1}$ instead of $2(4^{n-1})$. Also, since the starting point for $i = 1$ has a factor of $2^i = 2$ instead the summation, the common factor outside is $2^n$, not $2^{n+1}$. Finally, assuming you tried to use the actual summation instead of performing several steps at once, then note the summation has a factor of $3$ outside, with the exponents inside being $n - 2$, not $n - 1$. To see this, using the sum of a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Closed-form_formula) formula gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i=1}^{n-2}3^{n-1-i}2^{i} & = 2(3^{n-2})\left(\frac{1 - \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n-2}}{1 - \frac{2}{3}}\right) \\
& = 2(3^{n-2})\left(\frac{\frac{3^{n-2} - 2^{n-2}}{3^{n-2}}}{\frac{1}{3}}\right) \\
& = 2(3)(3^{n-2} - 2^{n-2})
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Regarding your step (5), here are a few more details. With $m = \left\lceil n\log_2 3 \right\rceil$ being the positive exponent $m$ which allows $2^m - 3^n \gt 0$, then since $2^{p_n} \gt 3^n$, we have $p_n \ge m$. This then gives from your linked answer for $n \gt 5$ that

$$2^{p_n} - 3^n \ge 2^{\left\lceil n\log_2 3 \right\rceil} - 3^n \gt 2^n \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Comment: For Case 2, here is my assumption:  $2\times3^n > 2^{p_n} > 3^n$ implies that $2^{p_n} = 2^{\left\lceil{n}\log_2{3}\right\rceil}$ so that $2^{p_n} - 3^n = 2^{\left\lceil{n}\log_2{3}\right\rceil} - 3^n > 2^n$ for $n > 5$

Comment: @LarryFreeman Thanks for explaining. It's getting too late for me (about midnight my time). I didn't notice that $\left\lceil n\log_2 3 \right\rceil$ is the smallest positive exponent $m$ which allows $2^m - 3^n \gt 0$. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @LarryFreeman FYI, one fairly minor point is that, as my updated answer states, my $(4)$ applies for all cases where $2^{p_n} \gt 3^n$. Thus, the two cases in your step (5) could have been combined into just one.

Comment: Yes.  You are right.  There is nothing gained from Case 1.  I should keep the argument simple.  I will update the question.

Answer (score 1):

***This is possibly rather a comment than an answer because I cannot pinpoint the exact position of the likely glitch in your arguments. However perhaps this derivation here implies some hint***

*update: I've misread Larry's notation of the $p_k$. So I replace my text introducing the exponents $A_k = \nu_2(3x_k+1)$ such that $p_1=A_1$, $p_2=A_1+A_2$ and $p_n=A_1+A_2+...+A_n$ where now also $P=p_n$ (for easier notation in the exponents). For an "1-cycle" all except one are $A_k=1$.*

---

The largest "stretch" between the smallest and the largest element $x_{\min}$ and $x_{\max}$ in an assumed cycle occurs if all but one (odd!) step are increasing, so the exponents except of only one are $A_k=1$ (this is then the "1-cycle"). And more concretely we have then about $x_\min = x_2$ and $$x_\max=x_1 = 1.5^{n-1} \cdot (x_2+1) -1 \tag 1$$ $\phantom {quad quad quad quad quad} $ <sub>This can be seen in my [short essay on the 1-cycle](https://go.helms-net.de/math/collatz/Collatz_1cycledisproof.pdf) in eq (3.1a) and (3.1b) on pg *4*.</sub>

Let us write:$$A_1+A_2+...+A_n =P (=p_n)$$ which is also (for this type of cycle) $$P \overset {\text{def}}=A_1+(n-1)\cdot 1 = (A_1-1)+n $$ then it is required that $P$ is such that $2^P \gt 3^n$ , or, let's take its minimal possible value $P=\lceil \gamma \cdot n \rceil$ where $\gamma = \log_2(3)\approx 1.58$.

From the equations of the "1-cycle" (for instance in my cited essay) we know that the minimal element is determinable by
$$ x_\min = { 3^n-2^n \over 2^P - 3^n }={ 2^P-2^n \over 2^P - 3^n }-1 = 2^n \cdot { 2^q-1 \over 2^P - 3^n }-1 \tag 2\\
 \small{\text{ where we introduce for notational easiness }q=A_1-1}
$$
Here the fraction-term $w_n \overset{\text{def}}= { 2^q-1 \over 2^P - 3^n } $ becomes the critical part for us, because we can proceed
$$ x_\max = 1.5^{n-1} \cdot (x_\min+1)-1 \\ 
=  1.5^{n-1} \cdot (2^n \cdot { 2^q-1 \over 2^P - 3^n }-1 +1)-1 \\
 = 1.5^{n-1} \cdot (2^n \cdot w_n)-1$$
$$ x_\max = 2 \cdot 3^{n-1} \cdot w_n -1 \overset?\le 3^n \tag 3
-1$$

Your question is answered to the positive if $w_n \le 1.5$ for all $n$.
 <sub>*update 2: Rereading the OP's post - your observation in "step 5" is sufficient that $w_n \lt 1$ for $n \gt 5$, and which introduces the non-elementary aspect of rational approximation and makes your conjecture safe. Sorry for not having seen this immediately*</sub>

---

However, I've never arrived at (or have seen) an elementary proof, that this is always the case, so I don't believe your derivation is without error *(but my answer hopefully gives some hint, where)*.
Actually the numerical analysis for small $n$ indeed confirm that $w\le 1$ *(compute the most critical cases for $n \in\{3,5,17,29,41,94,...\}$ from the generalized convergents of the continued fraction of $\gamma$)*, and for larger $n$ the theory of rational approximation of transcendental numbers (like it has been done for the disproof of the "1-cycle", see reference to Simons/deWeger in my essay) shall show that $w_n$ indeed will be smaller than $1$ for all $n \gt n_\min$.

So the conjecture is true, but something in your arguments has very likely a glitch.

---

Here empirical values for some $n$:

```
 n    w_n
 -----------
  1   1.0
  2   0.428571428571
  3   0.6
  4   0.148936170213
  5   0.538461538462
  6   0.0508474576271
  7   0.0162388685175
  8   0.0190067443286
  9   0.00481467329003
 10   0.00971173115462
 11   0.00149417038248
 12   0.000493101414524
 ...
```

and the list of the local maxima of that values, due to the convergents of the continued fraction of $\gamma$

```
 n    w_n
 -----------
  1   1.0
  3   0.6
  5   0.538461538462
 17   0.000201474525683
 29   0.0000000753989313627
 41   3.98990329587 E-11
 94   5.41070634693 E-27
 ...  ...
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your analysis.  Step(4) most likely has a gap.  If I figure it out, I will add it as an update to the question.

Comment: Note that one cycles are excluded when using $|(n+k) \log2 - n \log3| >\frac{1}{(\frac{3}{2})^n}>\frac{1}{2^n}$ (link point 5) since $|(n+k) \log2 - n \log3| <\frac{1}{2^n}$ for a 1-cycle (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3862457/is-this-argument-valid-for-showing-given-integers-n1-and-2m-3n-2m/3866590#3866590)

Comment: @Collag3n - hmm, I don't get your point at the moment, but if we exclude "1-cycles" then $x_\max$ is even smaller *(and $x_\min$ larger, because the covered range of all members $x_k$ contracts to their (roughly) average, when the $p_k$ vary more)* ... do you mean, that this makes an "elementary" proof of Larry's conjecture possibly easier?

Comment: The right side of equation (3) relies on conditions that are not compatible with the left side, so I am not sure they can be compared or that you can extract something from that. Indeed the "stretch" is not as large in this case.

Comment: note: Larry is also using the Rhin bound (used in the 1-cycle proof) in his development. If there is a "elementary" proof that could be used, I am not aware of it.

Comment: @Collag3n - I'm not sure I understand your comment containing "...of equation (3) relies..." Do you mean my eq (3) or that of Larry? If you actually mean my equation I do not understand what you want to say - I've rechecked it and don't have any idea...

Comment: In your inequality (3), the left side is an $x_{max}$ of a 1-cycle, but Larry's assertion that $x_{max}\leq 3^n-1$ (the right side of (3)) is based on  $2^{\left\lceil n\log_2 3 \right\rceil} - 3^n \gt 2^n$ which already proves a 1-cycle is not possible. So even if your inequality (3) is false, it doesn't mean Larry's assertion is (for cycles compatible with the Rhin bound). Now, it is possible I missed your point. I don't play much with Collatz these days.

Comment: @Collag3n - I think I've caught now a  misunderstanding. First step: of all possible cycles (of a certain length $n$) the 1-cycle has the smallest element $x_\min$ and the largest element $x_\max$. So if we can prove, that for the 1-cycle Larry's conjecture $x_\max<3^n$ holds, then this holds also for all other thinkable cyclic structures. Step 2: The apparatus for the 1-cycle has a formula which upper-bounds $x_\min$. Moreover it thus upper-bounds $x_\max \approx 1.5^{n-1} \cdot x_\min$. (...)

Comment: (...) Step 3: Rhin's formula gives, that for any 1-cycle we must have the upper bound of $x_\min$ such that $x_\max$ must be smaller then $3^n$ . (Unneeded step 4: A *modular condition* of an assumed 1-cycle requires that $x_\min$ is $2^n \cdot w -1$ with $w \gt 1$ But this is -by Rhin's limit- impossible, so no "1-cycle" can exist and any cycle -if one besides the trivial one exists at all- must have $x_\max \lt 3^n$ because $x_\min \ldots x_\max$ of the assumed cycle must lie *inside* the interval for the "1-cycle" structure, and which is determinable by the shown means)